# Вставить в таблицу MySQL данные из SELECT с промежуточной обработкой

Tags: php, mysql

Необходимо получить данные из таблицы - типа

```
    SELECT `id`, `fname`, `lname`, `sex`
    FROM `contacts`
    WHERE `id` > 10
      AND `id` < 100
```

Обработать их функцией типа:

```
public static function makeLeadKey ($fname = '', $lname = '', $sex = '')
{
    $code = (mb_strlen($fname) >= 2 ? mb_substr($fname, 0, 2) : '  ') .
    (mb_strlen($lname) >= 2 ? mb_substr($lname, 0, 2) : '  ') .
    (mb_strlen($sex) == 1 ? $sex : ' '));
    return mb_strlen($code) == 5 ? mb_strtoupper($code) : false;
}
```

И результат вставить обратно в таблицу типа:

```
   INSERT INTO `contacts` (`id`,`lead_key`)
        SELECT `id`, `fname`, `lname`, `sex`
        FROM `contacts`
        WHERE `id` > 10
          AND `id` < 100
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `lead_key` = VALUES(` ??? `)";
```

вопроса два:

1. как встроить обработку в запрос перед операцией вставки (хорошая практика) в MySQL 5.7, PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze19?
2. как бы вы искали ответ на такой вопрос в инете? мне там ответ найти не удалось

==============================================================

P.S. по советам в комментах решил обойтись запросом MySQL, но не удается подобрать синтаксис для более красивой логики в строках:

```
        CASE WHEN (`sex_id`) != 1 and (`sex_id`) != 2 
            then ' ' else '' end,
```

где пришлось добавить в нагрузку условие `else ''`  , без которого синтаксис не работает.
Общий текст запроса, который в результате работает как надо, такой:

```
 INSERT INTO `contacts` (`id`,`lead_match_code`) 
           SELECT `id`, concat(
                    CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(`fname`) > 1
                        then substr(`fname`, 1, 2) else '  ' end,
                    CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(`lname`) > 1
                        then substr(`lname`, 1, 2) else '  ' end,
                    CASE WHEN (`sex_id`) = 1
                        then 'M' else '' end,
                    CASE WHEN (`sex_id`) = 2
                        then 'F' else '' end,
                    CASE WHEN (`sex_id`) != 1 and (`sex_id`) != 2 
                        then ' ' else '' end,
                    CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(`birthday`) > 1
                    then replace(birthday,'-','') else '        ' end)
                FROM `contacts`
                WHERE `id`>10 
                  AND `id`<100 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `lead_match_code` = VALUES(`lead_match_code`);
```

прошу подсказать красивое решение без избыточной логики.

**Ответ (из комментов, автор @Mike):**

```
coalesce(elt(sex_id, 'M', 'F'), ' ')
```

Что до синтаксиса case можно было бы написать так

```
CASE sex_id WHEN 1 THEN 'M' WHEN 2 THEN 'F' ELSE ' ' END
```

Но функциями почти всегда короче, чем case. Кстати, если весь блок состоит только из одного THEN и ELSE то можно писать:

```
if(CHAR_LENGTH(fname) > 1, substr(fname, 1, 2), '  ')
```

но читабельность несколько снижается. хотя тут дело вкуса.

Comment: Если делать в php, то собственно работа разбивается на этапы: 1. получить данные; 2. обработать данные; 3. записать данные. Делать придется в цикле построчно. Искать в интернете соответственно нужные части, как прочитать, как записать.

Comment: Но я бы вообще не решал такую задачу на PHP. MySQL отлично может справится с преобразованиями строк (если кодировка в БД правильно настроена и она будет нормально понимать юникод). например code из вашей php функции пишется примерно как `concat(
    case when length(fname) >= 2 then substr(fname, 1, 2) else ' ' end,
    case when length(lname) >= 2 then substr(lname, 1, 2) else ' ' end,
    case when length(sex) == 1 then sex else ' ' end
)` И такую конструкцию вполне можно использовать в запросе типа `insert ... select` которая за одно действие все преобразует и вставит

Comment: вы бы лучше подумали, как такие операции провести без участия php

Comment: `coalesce(elt(sex_id, 'M', 'F'), ' ')`

Comment: Что до синтаксиса case можно было бы написать так `CASE sex_id WHEN 1 THEN 'M' WHEN 2 THEN 'F' ELSE ' ' END`. Но функциями почти всегда короче, чем case. Кстати, если весь блок состоит только из одного THEN и ELSE то можно писать `if(CHAR_LENGTH(fname) > 1, substr(fname, 1, 2), '  ')` но читабельность несколько снижается. хотя тут дело вкуса